# how to change the start day of week in full-calendar package in laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

I have installed fullcalendar package of laravel. The start day of week is Sunday but I want to change it to Saturday. Please help me
The below code shows my function in Controller

```
public function index(){
        $events = Event::get()
        ->where('deleted', '=', '0');
        $event_list = [];
        foreach ($events as $key => $event) {
            $event_list[] = Calendar::event(
                $event->event_name,
                false,
                new \DateTime($event->start_date),
                new \DateTime($event->end_date),
                $event->id,// added
                [
                    'color' => $event->event_color,//added
                ]
                // new \DateTime($event->end_date.' +1 day')
            );
        }
        $calendar_details = Calendar::addEvents($event_list);

        return view('events.index', compact('calendar_details') );
    }
```

In the above code it is note clear where to set the days of week and i do not know where and how to set the `Saturday` as start of the week instead of `Sunday`.
the problem is more clearly according `issued picture`.

And in below code is my event model:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Calendar;

class Event extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'event_name',
        'event_color',
        'start_date',
        'end_date',
    ];
}
```

[the issued picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztrGa.png)

Comment: Please post some code to show your effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$calendar = $calendar::setOptions(['firstDay' => 6,]);
```

Comment: Seems that 1 is [Monday](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/firstDay) not Saturday

Comment: where to add the above code?

Comment: Thanks It worked with the change of $calendar to Calendar